# MDX: How to Retrieve data Based on Latest Date For Each Student Id

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

[image]

How to get latest count based on date for each id.

Attempt:

```
SELECT [Measures].[CourseJoinedCount] ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY
        (
         [Course].[CourseName].[CourseName], 
         [DimDate].[Full Date].[Full Date],
         [Student].[StudentId].[StudentId]
        )ON ROWS 
FROM [RandD]
```

Comment: I try below query,                                                                         SELECT 
[Measures].[CourseJoinedCount] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY([Course].[CourseName].[CourseName],
    [DimDate].[Full Date].[Full Date],[Student].[StudentId].[StudentId])ON ROWS
FROM 
[RandD]

Comment: *please* add `code` formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the use of `Generate` might help. Currently untested but I will try an mock this up against `AdvWrks` tomorrow to see if it works:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
   [Measures].[CourseJoinedCount] ON 0, 
  Generate(
     [Course].[CourseName].[CourseName].MEMBERS
    ,[Course].[CourseName].CURRENTMEMBER
     *Tail(
       NonEmpty(
         [DimDate].[Full Date].[Full Date].MEMBERS,
         [Course].[CourseName].CURRENTMEMBER
       )
     )
  )
  *[Student].[StudentId].[StudentId]
  ON 1
FROM [RandD];
```

Comment: thanks for replaying , the above query very useful to me.

Comment: Hi whytheyq can u answer the below question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36152936/4903452

Comment: Hi whytheq,  can u please answer the this question                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171537/mdx-i-need-only-those-records-based-on-the-latest-date-and-latest-assesment-ans