# MDX How to retrieve data based on the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

[image]

How to retrieve data based on the latest date for that particular record only.

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (
      [DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA]
     ,[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]
     ,[DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key]
     ,Generate
      (
        [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text].MEMBERS
       ,
          [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CurrentMember
        * 
          Tail
          (
            NonEmpty
            (
              [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS
             ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CurrentMember
            )
           ,[DimPatient].[Patient Key]
          )
      )
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [CareManagement];
```

Comment: I Try query ,SELECT 
[Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY([DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA],
    [DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?],
    [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key],
    Generate(
     [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text].MEMBERS
    ,[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
     *TAIL(NonEmpty(
         [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS,
         [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].CURRENTMEMBER
   ),[DimPatient].[Patient Key]
  )))ON ROWS
FROM
[CareManagement]

Comment: why the radical edit?

Answer (score 0):

what you are after is probably LastNonEmpty aggregation

The LastNonEmpty function is a **semi-additive** function, and requires a dimension of type **Time** in order to be applicable (this can be set in the Dimension Properties), this is because it behaves differently when a measure is aggregating along the Time dimension, than it would when aggregating that same measure along any other (non-Time) dimension.

Taken from the following link: http://thinknook.com/ssas-lastnonempty-aggregation-function-2012-08-18/

- **LastNonEmpty Behavior along the Time Dimension**: The last (earliest) existing value along the time segment is returned, so if you are aggregating monthly, then the value on the last day of the month that has a value is returned.
- **LastNonEmpty Behavior along Non-Time Dimensions**: The SUM aggregation function is applied, and the value returned is the SUM of the measure along all aggregated (non-Time typed) dimensions.

Comment: I need particular record example, take the patientid-20066, the latest date is 2016-03-22.

Comment: For Your References:                                                                                                                        SELECT 
[Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY([DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA],
 [DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?],
 [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key],
 [DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text],
 [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key]
 ) ON ROWS
FROM 
[CareManagement]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong hierarchy inside the `Generate`?

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Assessment Patients Detail] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      {[DimAssessment].[Assessment Text].&[Employee Wellness HRA]}*
      {[DimAssessment].[Question Text].&[Do you use tobacco products?]}*
      {Generate
      (
        [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key].MEMBERS
       ,
          [DimPatient].[Patient Key].CurrentMember
        * 
          Tail
          (
            NonEmpty
            (
              [DimDate].[Full Date Alternate Key].[Full Date Alternate Key].MEMBERS
             ,[DimPatient].[Patient Key].CurrentMember
            )
          )
      )}*
      {[DimAssessment].[Answer Text].[Answer Text].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [CareManagement];
```

Here is a similar scenario in `AdvWrks` - several users on SO use this cube so we can all play:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      {
        [Customer].[Customer].[Alexis Thomas]
       ,[Customer].[Customer].[Carlos Morgan]
       ,[Customer].[Customer].[Carlos Scott]
      }*
      [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country]*
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It gives this:

[image]

I can start adding in the `Generate` attempt and I get as far as the following but as soon as I add in `Tail` the results disappear - unsure why it is behaving this way:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Generate
    (
      {
        [Customer].[Customer].[Alexis Thomas]
       ,[Customer].[Customer].[Carlos Morgan]
       ,[Customer].[Customer].[Carlos Scott]
      } AS S
     ,
        s.CurrentMember
      * 
        NonEmpty
        (
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
          * 
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country]
         ,s.CurrentMember
        )
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: hi whytheq,  when i executing above query i getting below error,                                                  Query (4, 7) The Multiply function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Comment: @yugandhar - ok we can be more explicit and add `{..}` around each bit of the multiplication - I will edit.

Comment: @whytheq- getting only one record, i need remaining records also, patientid-5250,17709,20066(2016-03-22),25839

Comment: @whytheq- getting only one record, i need remaining records also, patientid-5250,17709,20066(2016-03-22 latest date for that patientid-20066),25839

Comment: Hi whytheq , i need to remaining records also, can u please replay on this.

Comment: @whytheq- thanks for replaying the answers                                               but , i need the latest date sales amount like the customers               'Alexis Thomas    UnitedStates  February2008  $2,4000.34'                        'Carlos Morgan   Australia         February2008 $1,174.48'                                                                                               'Carlos Scott     France      January2008       $1,750.98 '

Comment: can u please replay on this