# Mdx aggregate field per person

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a table sample, sample belongs to patient, the relation is patient has many samples. Here is the schema:

```
Sample id    patient_id    result     date 
1            1             positive   2015 
2            2             positive   2015 
3            2             negative   2016
```

Could I sum the positive result by the max date for each patient?

---

SQL equivalent code:

```
select 
  sum(case when sout.result_id=1 then 1 else 0 end) 
from 
  samples sout ,
  ( 
     select max(sin.date) as maxdate, 
            sin.patient_id 
     from samples sin 
     where sin.date between date(${StartDateParam}) and date(${EndDateParam}) 
     group by sin.patient_id
  ) tmp 
where 
  sout.patient_id = tmp.patient_id and 
  sout.date = tmp.maxdate
```

Comment: Here is a sql version:select sum(case when sout.result_id=1 then 1 else 0 end)  from samples sout ,( select max(sin.date) as maxdate, sin.patient_id from samples sin where sin.date between date(${StartDateParam}) and date(${EndDateParam})  group by sin.patient_id) tmp where sout.patient_id = tmp.patient_id and sout.date = tmp.maxdate

Comment: Do you have some `mdx` that you have already tried? The structure of your cube is important  - creating custom measures based on mximum members is the sort of thing that is possible in `mdx`. If you have a samples dimension and a patient dimension then why would it not be possible. Also good if you could add tags for the server you use (SSAS?Mondrian?) and also the client for the `mdx` (SSRS?)

Comment: Thank you @whytheq

Comment: Recently I tried to answer this question which uses a maximum date per student so a little similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132898/mdx-how-to-retrieve-data-based-on-latest-date-for-each-student-id But we need to see your mdx to be able to help.

Comment: @whytheq I create a cube based on sample table,  date and location as two dimensions,  I can sum the all sample with positive, but I want to sum the last sample's result with positive group by patient? Do you have some link with have your mention about custom measure?
My understanding is to create a filter to group and find the last, then I can use measure to sum the samples.

Comment: SELECT {[Measures].[num_samples], [Measures].[num_rejected_samples]} ON COLUMNS, { [Geography.Admin].[MAPUTO CIDADE]} ON ROWS FROM [EIDCube_Joint] WHERE CurrentDateMember([Time.Date], '["Time.Date"]\.[yyyy]')

Comment: this does not seem to be related to the sql you posted?

Comment: You are right, because I didn't know how to create the measure and filter

Comment: Ok - I will need to play around with this on AdvWrks and then convert to Mondrian compliant - unable to access AdvWrks until later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @whytheq any response?

Comment: I still do not know even, the name, or structure of any of your dimensions/hierarchies/levels or measures in your cube: once I have an idea of these - _with an attempt at some mdx from yourself_ - then I am happy to spend some time trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

sample query for patient:
currently admitted :Select p.patient_no, p.pat_name,p.date_admitted,r.room_extension,p.date_discharged FROM Patient p JOIN room r ON p.room_location = r.room_location where p.date_discharged IS NULL ORDER BY p.patient_no,p.pat_name,p.date_admitted,r.room_extension,p.date_discharged;

vacant rooms: SELECT r.room_location, r.room_accomadation, r.room_extension FROM room r where r.room_location NOT IN (Select p.room_location FROM patient.p where p.date_discharged IS NULL) ORDER BY r.room_location, r.room_accomadation, r.room_extension;

no charges yet : SELECT p.patient_no, p.pat_name, COALESCE (b.charge,0.00) charge FROM patient p LEFT JOIN billed b on p.patient_no = b.patient_no WHERE p.patient_no NOT IN (SELECT patient_no FROM billed) group by p.patient_no ORDER BY p.patient_no, p.pat_name,charge;

max salarised : SELECT phy_id,phy_name, salary FROM physician where salary in (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM physician) UNION
SELECT phy_id,phy_name, salary FROM physician where salary in (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM physician) ORDER BY phy_id,phy_name, salary;

various item consumed by: select p.pat_name, i.discription, count (i.item code) as item code from patient p join billed b on p.patient no = b. patient no join item i on b.item code = i.item code group by p.patient no, i.item code order by..

patient not receivede treatment: SELECT p.patient_no,p.pat_name FROM patient p where p.patient_no NOT IN (SELECT t.patient_no FROM treats t) 
ORDER BY p.patient_no,p.pat_name;

2 high paid : Select phy_id, phy_name, date_of_joining, max(salary) as salary from physician group by salary having salary IN (Select salary from physician)
Order by phy_id, phy_name, date_of_joining, salary limit 2;

over 200: select patient_no, sum (charge), as total charge from billed group by patient no having total charges > 200 order by patient no, total charges